# Calculating spectrum and resolvent set of a linear operator (General question).

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am currently taking a course on functional analysis and we discussed spectral theory. I am having a lot of trouble with the following type of exercises

> Given a linear operator $T: X \rightarrow X$ that is defined like (bla). Calculate the spectrum and resolvent set.

Does there exist a general approach to such problems? A good general strategy to solve such exercises? Because it seems to me that for every problem there could be a whole different strategy.

Sincerely, a confused undergrad. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define spectrum and resolvent set only for $T:X\to X$. Are there any examples in the course you take? Do you know what is the spectrum of a matrix?

Comment: Oh yes my bad, I changed it. No we did not have any examples other than that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ the spectrum $\sigma (A)$ of a linear bounded operator $A$ are its eigenvalues, i.e. the spectrum is equal to the point spectrum.

Comment: There's not a general approach. The idea is to gather a good collection of examples that you can analyze, such as multiplication operators, integral and differential operators, and operators defined using a Schauder basis in Banach space or an orthogonal basis in Hilbert space. This will help you test hypotheses concerning operators.